# What privileges should I give to a user who can access my SFTP but only reads them

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, sudo, sftp

I have a current root user which is able to do, well **ROOT** privileges on my SFTP running on Ubuntu LTS 12.04. I'm planning on adding a new user that can only read a specific directory inside my sftp. probably just inside the www/ folder. What privileges should I gave?

Comment: What do you mean by `What privileges should I give? `? Do you mean file permissions or something like an `acl`?

Comment: what do you mean by acl?

Comment: i just want the user to read on www/ folder.

Comment: Chroot into the directory and run internal-sftp. Permissions in chroot does not matter much.

Comment: You can set file/folder **acl** (**Access Control List**) you can allow certain groups/users to `read, write, execute`